# update src but play previous file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play music when the user clicks the div, however, when the user clicks the div the src changes, but the audio tag still plays the previous file

Here is the code

```js
function music1() {
  document.getElementById("audiosrc").src = "j.mp3";
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="audio" loop autoplay>
<source id="audiosrc" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9473/new_year_dubstep_minimix.ogg" type="audio/ogg">Your browser dose not Support the audio Tag
</audio>
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? I see no event handling, tell me what you want to do exactly, and what div the user clicks, I see no div. pls provide you whole code

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the new src to the audio element. Using `.load()` function solves this.

```js
function changeSrc() {
  const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  const source = document.getElementById("audiosrc");
  source.src = "https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/yeah-boymp4.mp3"
  audio.load();
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="audio" loop autoplay>
  <source id="audiosrc" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9473/new_year_dubstep_minimix.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser dose not Support the audio Tag
</audio>

<button onclick="changeSrc()">change src</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`load` it after change

```js
function music1(){  
  audiosrc.src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg";
  audio.load();
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="audio" loop autoplay>
<source id="audiosrc" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9473/new_year_dubstep_minimix.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser dose not Support the audio Tag
</audio>
<br/>
<button onclick="music1()">new</button>
```